# How to use json API information from python requests

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, twitch

I want to be able to read json API information and depending on the information make something happen. For example:

I get this information from a Streamelements API.

```json
{
"donation":{
"user":{
"username":"StreamElements"
"geo":"null"
"email":"streamelements@streamelements.com"
}
"message":"This is a test"
"amount":100
"currency":"USD"
}
"provider":"paypal"
"status":"success"
"deleted":false
"_id":"5c0aab85de9a4c6756a14e0d"
"channel":"5b2e2007760aeb7729487dab"
"transactionId":"IMPORTED"
"createdAt":""2018-12-07T17:19:01.957Z""
"approved":"allowed"
"updatedAt":""2018-12-07T17:19:01.957Z""
}
```

I then want to check if the amount on that specific tip is $10 and if that is the case I want something to happen.

This is what I have so far but I do not know how to get the right variable:

```py
data = json.loads(url.text)
if (data[0]['amount'] == 10):
   DoTheThing();
```

Comment: I think it should be `data[0]['donation']['amount']`

Answer (score 0):

The `amount` field is under the inner `donation` object:

```
data = json.loads(url.text)
donation_amount = data["donation"]["amount"]
if donation_amount == 10:
    # do something
```

Verified using the [Stream Elements Tips API documentation](https://docs.streamelements.com/reference/tips).

Comment: I saw someone use print(data[0]['something'], what would the 0 do in this case?

Comment: @Androtex you don't need `data[0]` as your response loaded with JSON would be a dictionary which we access by the `donation` key.

Comment: So if there would be for example a group of different donators i would need to use `data[0]['donation']['amount']` for the first one in that list?

Comment: @Androtex no, if it is a list of this kind of objects, you'd iterate over them: `for obj in data:` and then in the loop body, you'd do `donation_amount = obj["donation"]["amount"]`. Experiment, print out intermediate values, don't guess - check yourself.

Comment: I am asking because I did just that. I tested another api with a list of the recent 25 tips and when I used this `donation_amount = data["docs"][0]["donation"]["amount"]` it worked, why is that?